# Washer and slice method for finding revolution about the $y$ and $x$-axis

Tags: calculus

> For the region in the fourth quadrant bounded by $y=x^2-16​$, the​ $x$-axis, and​ $y$-axis, determine which of the following is​ greater: the volume of the solid generated when the region is revolved about the​ $x$-axis or about the​ $y$-axis.

The first answer I figured it out which was $\frac{8192}{15} \pi$. However, now it is requesting when the region is revolved about the​ $y$-axis. Can someone help be with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just evaluate the following:

$$\pi \int_{-16}^0 x^2 \, dy = \pi \int_{-16}^0 y + 16 \, dy$$

If you know the formula for the $x$-axis, you can perform similar trick, we just have to switch the role of $x$ and $y$.

Edit:
\begin{align}\pi \int_{-16}^0 x^2 \, dy &= \pi \int_{-16}^0 y + 16 \, dy \\
&= \pi \left[\frac{y^2}2 +16y\right]_{-16}^{0}\\
&=\pi\left[\frac{0^2-(-16)^2}2 + 16(0-(-16)) \right]\\
&=\pi\frac{16^2}2\\
&=2^7\pi \\
&=128\pi\end{align}

Comment: I know this is a silly question but why is the expression y+16.

Comment: $y= x^2-16$, hence $x^2 = y+16$.

Comment: I got -128pi is this right

Comment: negative value?

Comment: I dont know how i got that answer

Comment: edited my post, i think it should be $128\pi$.